# Populating combobox with layers in TOC using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, pyqt

I am developing a plugin, and I want user to select one of the loaded layers from a combobox. I've already coded this much:

```
self.dlg.show()
    layerlist = []
    self.dlg.ui.layerCombo.clear()  # clear the combo 
    layermap = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers()
    for name, layer in layermap.iteritems():
        if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer:
            if layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line:
                layerlist.append( unicode( layer.name() ) )
    for layer in layerlist:    # foreach layer in legend 
        self.dlg.ui.layerCombo.addItem( layer )
```

**First Question:** I get the error

> IndexError: list index out of range

which I don't quite know why.

**Second Question:** Am I doing the right thing? I couldn't find a tutorial on this. Where is the best place to put this code (run, initGui,...)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values()
for layer in layers:
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.geometryType() == QGis.Line:
       self.dlg.ui.layerCombo.addItem( layer.name(), layer )
```

You can then get the layer from the combo like this:

```
index = self.dlg.ui.layerCombo.currentIndex()
layer = self.dlg.ui.layerCombo.itemData(index)
```

Comment: Thanks alot, it works great! just a follow up question: I put the first part of code in "run" method. is that the right place in general? I guess I haven't really understood what run does exactly.

Comment: With the plugin builder default plugin, I had to remove ".ui" to make it work. Otherwise this is great!